# GregorianCalendar changing my date when my defined time or system time is 12:00 Pm

Tags: java, gregorian-calendar

I am using below code for date time, but when my startTime="12:00 Pm" my eventDate moving next date and also when system time is 12:00 Pm also my date is moving to next date.

help me whats wrong in this code.

```
 Date appt = new Date();
 Calendar apptDate = new GregorianCalendar();
 apptDate.setTime(appt);

 String startTime = "11:00 Pm";

 String[] appointmentHourMinute = startTime.split(":");
 String hour = appointmentHourMinute[0];
 String[] minuteAmPm = appointmentHourMinute[1].split(" ");
 String minute = minuteAmPm[0];
 String amPm = minuteAmPm[1];
 int hourInt = Integer.parseInt(hour);
 int minInt = Integer.parseInt(minute);

 Calendar eventDate = new GregorianCalendar();
 eventDate.set(Calendar.MONTH, apptDate.get(Calendar.MONTH));
 System.out.println("Display Month"+ apptDate.get(Calendar.MONTH));
 eventDate.set(Calendar.DATE, apptDate.get(Calendar.DATE));
 System.out.println("Display Month"+ apptDate.get(Calendar.DATE));
 eventDate.set(Calendar.YEAR, apptDate.get(Calendar.YEAR));
 System.out.println("Display Month"+ apptDate.get(Calendar.YEAR));
 eventDate.set(Calendar.HOUR, hourInt);
 eventDate.set(Calendar.MINUTE, minInt);
 eventDate.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);      
 if (amPm.equalsIgnoreCase("AM")){
     if(hourInt==12)
         eventDate.set(Calendar.AM_PM,Calendar.PM);
     else
         eventDate.set(Calendar.AM_PM,Calendar.AM);         
 }else{
     if(hourInt==12)
         eventDate.set(Calendar.AM_PM,Calendar.AM);
     else
         eventDate.set(Calendar.AM_PM,Calendar.PM);   
 }
```

Comment: And what are you trying to achieve actually?

Comment: obligatory http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 0):

First you tell the date that you want 12:00, which it interprets as a 24h time, i.e. noon. Next you tell it that you want to have a "P.M." time. As Inderstand it, this use of "P.M." for noon or midnight is ambiguous, and might often denote noon. But it seems that in this particular case, Java will interpret it as midnight. In general, it assumes that A.M. times are in the first half of the day, so when you switch from A.M. to P.M. it can simply add 12 to the hours field. Which dumps you at 0:00 of the next day.

If you want to avoid that, you might want to set the time first and the date afterwards. Which in your case means reading the date first and restoring it later on. As an alternative, you might do this +12h handling yourself, with a special case turning 24:00 back to 0:00.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. As per your instruction i moved my time code before date code. But still i am getting the same date issues only.

Comment: Calendar eventDate = new GregorianCalendar();    
     eventDate.set(Calendar.HOUR, hourInt);
     eventDate.set(Calendar.MINUTE, minInt);
     eventDate.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);  
     eventDate.set(Calendar.MONTH, apptDate.get(Calendar.MONTH));
     eventDate.set(Calendar.DATE, apptDate.get(Calendar.DATE));
     eventDate.set(Calendar.YEAR, apptDate.get(Calendar.YEAR));
     
     //eventDate = cal;
     if (amPm.equalsIgnoreCase("AM")){ 
     eventDate.set(Calendar.AM_PM,Calendar.AM);         
     }else{
     eventDate.set(Calendar.AM_PM,Calendar.PM);   
     }